# Plotting a curve from dots of a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, scikit-learn

I'm facing a silly problem while plotting a graph from a regression function calculated using sci-kit-learn. After constructing the function I need to plot a graph that shows X and Y from the original data and calculated dots from my function. The problem is that my function is not a line, despite being linear, it uses a Fourier series in order to give the right shape for my curve, and when I try to plot the lines using:

```
ax.plot(df['GDPercapita'], modelp1.predict(df1), color='k')
```

I got a Graph like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b41J.png)

But the trhu graph is supposed to be a line following those black points:

[Dots to be connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xImE6.png)

I'm generating the graph using the follow code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['GDPercapita'], df['LifeExpectancy'], edgecolors=(0, 0, 0))
ax.scatter(df['GDPercapita'], modelp1.predict(df1),color='k') #this line is changed to get the first pic.
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show(block=True)
```

Does anyone have an idea about what to do?

POST DISCUSSION EDIT:

Ok, so first things first:
The data can be download at: http://www.est.ufmg.br/~marcosop/est171-ML/dados/worldDevelopmentIndicators.csv

I had to generate new data using a Fourier expasion, with normalized values of GDPercapita, in order to perform an exhaustive optimization algorithm for Regression Function used to predict the LifeExpectancy, and found out the number o p parameters that generate the best Regression Function, this number is p=22.
Now I have to generate a Polynomial Function using the predictions points of the regression fuction with p=22, to show how the best regression function is compared to the Polynomial function with the 22 degrees.
To generate the prediction I use the following code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
modelp22 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
modelp22.fit(xp22,y_train)
df22 = df[p22]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['GDPercapita'], df['LifeExpectancy'], edgecolors=(0, 0, 0))
ax.scatter(df['GDPercapita'], modelp22.predict(df22),color='k') 
ax.set_xlabel('GDPercapita')
ax.set_ylabel('LifeExpectancy')
plt.show(block=True)
```

Now I need to use the predictions points to create a Polynomial Function and plot a graph with: The original data(first scatter), the predictions points(secont scatter) and the Polygonal Funciontion (a curve or plot) to show their visual relation.

Comment: It looks like your points are not being passed in order. Is df1 sorted by "GDPercapita"?

Comment: You need to sort your data before plotting.

Comment: Yes, and after sorting both GDPercapita and LifeExpectancy I still get a messy curve!    

dfnew = df.sort_values(by='LifeExpectancy')

df1 = dfnew[p1]

Comment: Did you try to sort by `GDPercapita`?

Comment: yes I did and got the same messy graph, the thing is that I have to fit a curve in the form of a polygonal function that passes thru my prediction data point

Comment: @LeandroEleutério  I see two problems here: one is to plot the graph with both the data points and the model, but the first aspect is to correctly fit a model on the data point... the current model do not seem to be correct, I don't know for which problem the question is mainly about? (For the fit: Is a "polygonal function" a [polynomial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial), or [polygonal line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain)?) Could you include some limited number of your data, so we can test build an example?

Comment: @zdze2 sure, let me edit the post and add something more !